# I want to add popover/overlay/hotspot on the streetview of google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, google-street-view

What I want is to tag some objects in streetview by an icon. And as the streetview rotates the  hotspot icon should also move with it, As i have shown in bellow images that the tag should be moving along with the map. The images are just self edited. but i want this in the streetview by specifying the angle, pinch and latLong values.

[image]

So is there any way for this....?.

bellow is the simple code i have written to call the stretview app of phone through intent.

```
Intent streetView = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=33.748832,-84.38751300000001"+"&cbp=1,90,,0,1.0&mz=8"));
    startActivity(streetView);
```

Other ways for performing  same this are also wellcome...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though my question was criticized I found an alternate way to do this.

What i have done is, created Google map street-view using Google map JavaScript api v3 which is compatible with both desktop browser and mobile browsers. And then added that in `assest` folder of android application package and displayed it on android webview. Then accepting the value of x coordinate from accelerometer and passing it to the webview by webviewInterface on each update and setting the heading of map with it.