# mark a building/obejct on Google street view

Tags: google-maps, view, overlay

I want to tag (or mark) a building (or object) on Google street view in my web pages, and i  find a solution that works on Android APP (JavaScript/WebView) in the article" [I want to add popover/overlay/hotspot on the streetview of google map in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418418/i-want-to-add-popover-overlay-hotspot-on-the-streetview-of-google-map-in-android)." But the solution is not for web pages.

Is any solution available for web pages?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I find a post that is a tutorial of how to create custom Street View. Please reference it. http://blog.mridey.com/2010/05/how-to-create-and-display-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

Use google.maps.Marker class

```
function initialize() {

        var hongkongolympic = new google.maps.LatLng(22.320701, 114.160688);

        var mapOptions = {
                center: hongkongolympic,
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: hongkongolympic,
                map: map,
                title: "Hello World!"
        });

        var panoramaOptions = {
                position: hongkongolympic,
                pov: {
                        heading: 150,
                        pitch: 10
                }
        };

        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);

        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: hongkongolympic,
                map: panorama
        });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```